# How to choose which comes first when specifying OR in MySQLi SELECT statement

Tags: select, mysqli

When you retrieve data through a MySQLi statement such as the following:

```
$sqls = "SELECT * FROM course WHERE course='$product_id_array' OR course='Both' ORDER BY ...";
$sqlsresults = mysqli_query($db_conx,$sqls);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sqlsresults)) {
    $selectedContent = $row["content"];
    $selectedTitle = $row["title"];
}
```

Is there a way to output the match for `'both'` first?  Would this be as simple as re-arranging the order of the `WHERE` portion of the statement?

Comment: Can you please rephrase your question?

Comment: wow, yes of course. I just read that again and it makes no sense. I promise English is my first language!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `ORDER BY` explicitly sorts only by `id`. There is no way around this in the `WHERE` part of your query. To change how results are ordered, use `ORDER BY`.

```
SELECT *
FROM course
WHERE course=...
OR course='Both'
ORDER BY CASE course WHEN 'Both' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ASC, id DESC
```

Unrelated note: if `$product_id_array` contains untrusted user input, the user can put things like `'; DELETE FROM course; --` in there. Read up on parameterized queries to learn how to prevent that.

Comment: The $product_id_array is from the database. Is this what you mean @hvd?

Comment: @Chris That's not enough information to be able to tell. It's unsafe if there is any way for an untrusted user to manipulate the value of that variable. That means, if it comes straight from the database, what matters is whether untrusted users can fill that field.

Comment: The variable itself does at one point come from the user at sign up and upon selection. Similar to any other variable would. 

It is not something that is actively adjusted. Is that more clear? It is basically saying, "This customer purchased this". It isn't an output of user selection for a search. Does that make more sense? 

Also, can you explain a little bit more about the 'CASE' section. I'm unsure on how to utilize this.

Comment: @Chris No, not "any other variable". There are a lot of cases where variables do not come from user input in any way. Anyway, that wasn't the point of your question. About `CASE`: the value of `CASE course WHEN 'Both' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END` is `0` if `course = 'Both'`, `1` otherwise. Think of it as a virtual column. Since `0 < 1`, ordering by that will cause the records with `course = 'Both'` to appear first.